# How to used FatSecret API in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using FatSecretAPI to retreive items from their database.

But when I request to FatSecret API, they give me some key word to used in Android Studio. But i dont know how to write key code to my program.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to initialize Request with your

1. **Fatsecret Application Consumer Key**,
2. **Associated Consumer Secret**
3. **Listener which takes care of all the data**;

and you are good to search all data items or get any particular item; search within items.

From [Official Documentation](http://www.fatsecret4j.com/android).